# Subform field hyperlinks to open record in another form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to replicate a feature in the Access 2007 "Issues" template/example database. When you open up the 'Issues List' form, and click on an ID, it behaves like a hyperlink and opens up that record in another form.

How can I replicate this? I'm not a big fan of using the Access 'create macro' feature and would prefer to use the VBA editor if possible.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't examine that template database, but your description sounds like something you can handle with [DoCmd.OpenForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx).

Say your form includes a text box named *txtID* which is bound to a numeric field, *ID*, in the form's record source.  Create a VBA procedure for the text box's click event to pass the current `ID` value as the `OpenForm` *WhereCondition* parameter.  (This assumes the record source of the next form also includes that numeric `ID` field.)

```vb
Private Sub txtID_Click()
    Const cstrForm As String = "YourNextFormName" ' <-- change this
    DoCmd.OpenForm cstrForm, WhereCondition:="[ID]=" & Me.txtID
End Sub
```

If the data type of the `ID` field is text rather than numeric, include quotes around the value in the *WhereCondition*.

```vb
WhereCondition:="[ID]='" & Me.txtID & "'"
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is first set the text field you're interested to a hyperlink.  You do this by setting `Display As Hyperlink` in the `Format` tab of the `Property Sheet` or you can do this via vba as following (although it seems to be bugged visually i.e. clickable link but not displayed as such)

```
myTextBox.DisplayAsHyperlink = acDisplayAsHyperlinkOnScreenOnly
```

After you do that, create a `Click` event.  In the subroutine you can run the code to open your form filtered with the record number (or appropriate argument)

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "myFormName", acNormal, , "[ID]=" & Nz([Id], 0)
```

Comment: HansUp's answer is more in depth on how to implement `OpenForm`.  I'm leaving my answer up in case you want the hyperlink functionality as well.

Comment: Underlined when you edit the property via VBA?  I get it underlined when I do it set it manually through the `Property Sheet` but not when I set it via VBA